# food web text files into a dictionary- python 3

Tags: python-3.x

how can I turn the file into dictionary?

I must load all of the data from the food web file into a dictionary that describes the eats relationship.  The keys in the dictionary will by the names of the predators (which is the first element).  The values in the dictionary will be lists, where each element in the list is the name of a prey animal that the predator eats.

`Goat,Plants
Jackal,Goat,Rabbit
Kite,Snake,Mouse
Lion,Goat,Jackal,Wild Cat
Mouse,Plants
Owl,Mouse
Rabbit,Plants
Snake,Mouse
Wild Cat,Rabbit,Mouse`

the output should look like this:

`Predators and Prey:
  Goat eats Plants
  Jackal eats Goat and Rabbit
  Kite eats Mouse and Snake
  Lion eats Goat, Jackal and Wild Cat
  Mouse eats Plants
  Owl eats Mouse
  Rabbit eats Plants
  Snake eats Mouse
  Wild Cat eats Mouse and Rabbit`

Answer (score 0):

If text file is 'dictionary.txt'-

```
dic = dict()
with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = line.strip().split(',')
        dic[words[0]] = [words[1:]]
```